# htaccess isn't doing what I wanted it to do

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
#### ADMINISTRATION PANEL ####
RewriteRule ^administration/main administration/index.php [L]                                       ## Administration - Main
RewriteRule ^administration/members/list administration/members.php?list=view [L]                   ## Administration - User List
RewriteRule ^administration/members/reports administration/members.php?reports=view [L]             ## Administration - User Reports
RewriteRule ^administration/members/banned administration/members.php?banned=view [L]               ## Administration - User Banned

RewriteRule ^administration/members/list/page([^/]*)$ administration/members.php?list=view&page=$1 [L]          ## Administration - User List - Pagination
RewriteRule ^administration/members/reports/page([^/]*)$ administration/members.php?reports=view&page=$1 [L]    ## Administration - User Reports  - Pagination
RewriteRule ^administration/members/banned/page([^/]*)$ administration/members.php?banned=view&page=$1 [L]      ## Administration - User Banned  - Pagination
```

If I use the direct link "administration/members.php?list=view&page34 it works..... But nope, not with htaccess rewrites, total bs. Help me?

Comment: Give this site a try: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: @Mike, It didn't say anything.... It just said debugging, didn't really specify if there was an issue or not.

Comment: @user3615435 it showed me exactly what was wrong. Your first set of patterns are too generic. They will match the request before the later patterns.

Comment: Can you screenshot it, not able to see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you have to remember about rewrite rules is that they are regular expression matchers. Your issue is that this pattern

```
^administration/members/list
```

will match this URL

```
http://example.com/administration/members/list/page34
```

before this rule

```
^administration/members/list/page([^/]*)$
```

I suggest you put an EOL anchor (`$`) on your first set of patterns if that's what they are to actually match, eg

```
RewriteRule ^administration/main$ administration/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^administration/members/list$ administration/members.php?list=view [L]
RewriteRule ^administration/members/reports$ administration/members.php?reports=view [L]
RewriteRule ^administration/members/banned$ administration/members.php?banned=view [L]
```

I also suggest you use the `QSA` flag so as not to lose any extra query string information.

#### Update

An even better idea would be to combine your first set of rules with their *paged* equivalents. For example

```
RewriteRule ^administration/members/list(/page(\d+))? administration/members.php?list=view&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

This will end up like this...

```
administration/members/list        => administration/members.php?list=view&page=
administration/members/list/page34 => administration/members.php?list=view&page=34
```

Comment: I'm the biggest newbie when it comes to .htaccess. Going to test now, I'll let you know in a few minutes!

Comment: So I switched around the list=view so now it's view=list.. And it works now :) Thanks, I've also looked at your EOL examples and your updated post. I honestly thank you for taking the time out of your life to help me!